# caption problem

Tags: captions

I have placed the caption at the bottom of the table, when I click in the table list it takes me to the next page from the caption. Is there a solution with hyperref to go to caption page?[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\usepackage{textpos}

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=plain,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

\usepackage{tikz}



\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\  Fondamenti di Informatica}} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} Luca \\ \textbf{Cognome:} Longo \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} blabla} 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} 21-22}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}


\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Introduzione}
Il proposito di questa introduzione è quello di mostrare i punti chiave del progetto, in modo tale da avere un'idea di come si arriverà all'elaborato finale. \\
Prendendo in considerazione la sola parte numerica della Matricola personale, se ne ricaverà il \emph{resto} dividendo per $ 2^{2^4} $, ed in seguito si provvederà a codificarlo in binario al fine di ottenere una Funzione Booleana di 16bit a quattro variabili (x,y,z,w). \\
In seguito verranno identificati i termini minimi, \emph{"minterm"}, e i termini massimi, \emph{"Maxterm"}, termini in cui la funzione assume rispettivamente valori 1 e 0, di cui si provvederà a ricaverane le espressioni.  \\
Nei passi successivi, le espressioni di minterm e maxterm verranno entrambe semplificate nel seguente modo:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Per \emph{via algebrica}, attraverso l'utilizzo degli assiomi A1-A7 e dei teoremi T1-T10;
\end{itemize}
Verrà dimostrata l'effetiva esattezza dei calcoli mostrando l'equivalenza dei \mbox{risultati} di entrambe le semplificazioni, dopodichè si procederà alla semplificazione dei minterm in altri due modi differenti: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Mediante \emph{mappa di Karnaugh};
    \item Metodo \emph{tabellare Quine-Mc Cluskey};
\end{itemize} 
Infine, per avere un quadro più chiaro, verranno predisposti i disegni degli schemi logici basati su porte \emph{"AND}, \emph{"OR"} , \emph{"NOT"} , delle semplificazioni illustrate nel passo precedente.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduzione}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\section{Individuazione Funzione Booleana associata \mbox{alla} matricola}

Acquisito il numero di matricola, si procede nell'individuazione della Funzione Booleana associata; \\

\hspace{12pt}\textbf{Numero Matricola: blabla}
\begin{enumerate}
 
    \item Elisione del prefisso "IN" per ricavarne la sola parte numerica
    \item Divisione della parte numerica per $ 2^{2^4} $ affinché se ne ricavi il resto: \\

$ 0501032 \div 2^{2^4} = 501032 \div 65536= 7*65536+42280 $ \\

Il resto è= 42280

\item Codifica del resto in binario tramite divisione per 2, operazione ripetuta per ogni quoziente ottenuto. Il resto di ogni divisione, formato da 0 o 1, comporrà la stringa binaria:

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r | c}
    
        42280 & 0\\
        21140 & 0\\
        10570 & 0\\
        5285 & 1\\
        2642 & 0\\
        1321 & 1\\
        660 & 0\\
        330 & 0\\
        165 & 1\\
        82 & 0\\
        41 & 1\\
        20 & 0\\
        10 & 0\\
        5 & 1\\
        2 & 0\\
        1 & 1\\
        0 & /\\
    
\end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Codifica del resto in binario}
    \label{tab: bin} 
\end{center}


\begin{textblock*}{180pt}(270pt, -320 pt)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0, -9.8) {};
    \node (B) at (0, 0) {};
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}
\newpage

Il risultato derivante dalla codifica, letto dal basso verso l'alto come \mbox{indicato} dalla freccia della Tabella (\ref{tab: bin}), è il seguente: \\

\hspace{4cm} $42280_{10}= \bm{1010010100101000_{2}}$ \\

\item Si avrà una Funzione Booleana a quattro variabili associata alla stringa binaria "1010010100101000":
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc||c} 
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x, y, z, w)$ \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 

\end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Funzione Booleana a quattro variabili associata alla stringa binaria}
    \label{tab: Fun} 
\end{center}
\newpage

bla bla vla


\end{document}
```

Comment: Without to see a document example, which reproduce your problem, is impossible to help your

Comment: Hello, i added code

Comment: Your document example has errors: (i) list `enumerate` doesn't contain any `\item` instruction, (ii) float should not be enclosed in some environment (in your case `textblock`. Please, correct your document example. BTW, I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why is your tablukar outside the table environment? Tabular and caption should both be inside the table environment that is the whole point

Comment: I deleted items by mistake.i removed textblock. Table doesn't contain tabular because I want the caption below the table. By doing the opposite, the table rises to the top of the page. I corrected the code

Comment: the problem is not resolved

Comment: Don't use `center` for the captioned table; use `table` and let it float. Just add a `\ref` at the point where you describe the table.

Comment: I removed the caption from \center, but the problem is not solved. When I click on the link it takes me to the next page, as in the picture

Comment: Not the question you are asking, but captions go on the *top* of tables. They only go on the bottom of figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such big tables will almost certainly give pagination problems. Let them float: the purpose of the caption with its `\label` is to be able to refer to the table by their caption number.

Please, have a look at the edited version of your typescript. Main points:

1. Separate package loading and settings
2. Never use `"`, but double quotes as shown (if they're needed, I'd prefer to set the in upright type)
3. Never use `\\` to terminate paragraphs, but a blank line.
4. While the first two `\newpage` commands make sense, the others don't.
5. In order to avoid duplicate anchors which confuse `hyperref` I use `\pagenumbering{Alph}` in the front matter and `\pagestyle{empty}`.
6. The up arrow can be obtained much more easily, see `tab:bin`.

I offer two versions of the second table; doing it with sixteen rows is a big waste of space, so I printed the split one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <-- should be last

%%% settings
% geometry
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=4cm,
  bottom=4cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  heightrounded,
  bindingoffset=5mm,
  headheight=14.5pt, % <-- as requested by fancyhdr
}

% hyperref
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

% titlesec
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {0pt}
  {20pt}

% caption
\captionsetup{
  skip=20pt,
  format=plain,
  position=bottom,
  font=small,
  labelformat=parens,
  labelfont=bf
}

% fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}


\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\[0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\  Fondamenti di Informatica}} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\[0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} Luca \\ \textbf{Cognome:} Longo \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} blabla} 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} 21-22}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
%    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}% <-- I don't have it
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\[0.2cm]
    \Large\texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Elettronica - Informatica} 
\end{center}

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Introduzione}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduzione}
\thispagestyle{plain}

Il proposito di questa introduzione è quello di mostrare i punti 
chiave del progetto, in modo tale da avere un'idea di come si 
arriverà all'elaborato finale.

Prendendo in considerazione la sola parte numerica della Matricola 
personale, se ne ricaverà il \emph{resto} dividendo per $ 2^{2^4}$, 
ed in seguito si provvederà a codificarlo in binario al fine di 
ottenere una Funzione Booleana di 16bit a quattro variabili $(x,y,z,w)$.

In seguito verranno identificati i termini minimi, ``\emph{minterm}'', 
e i termini massimi, ``\emph{Maxterm}'', termini in cui la funzione 
assume rispettivamente valori 1 e 0, di cui si provvederà a ricaverane 
le espressioni.

Nei passi successivi, le espressioni di minterm e maxterm verranno 
entrambe semplificate nel seguente modo:
\begin{itemize}
\item Per \emph{via algebrica}, attraverso l'utilizzo degli assiomi 
A1--A7 e dei teoremi T1--T10;
\end{itemize}
Verrà dimostrata l'effetiva esattezza dei calcoli mostrando 
l'equivalenza dei \mbox{risultati} di entrambe le semplificazioni, 
dopodiché si procederà alla semplificazione dei minterm in altri due 
modi differenti: 
\begin{itemize}
\item Mediante \emph{mappa di Karnaugh};
\item Metodo \emph{tabellare Quine-Mc Cluskey};
\end{itemize} 
Infine, per avere un quadro più chiaro, verranno predisposti i disegni 
degli schemi logici basati su porte ``\emph{AND}'', ``\emph{OR}'' , 
``\emph{NOT}'' , delle semplificazioni illustrate nel passo precedente.


\section{Individuazione Funzione Booleana associata \mbox{alla} matricola}

Acquisito il numero di matricola, si procede nell'individuazione della 
Funzione Booleana associata
\begin{quote}
\textbf{Numero Matricola: blabla}
\end{quote}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Elisione del prefisso ``IN'' per ricavarne la sola parte numerica;
\item Divisione della parte numerica per $ 2^{2^4} $ affinché se ne 
ricavi il resto $ 0501032 \div 2^{2^4} = 501032 \div 65536= 7*65536+42280 $;
il resto è $42280$

\item Codifica del resto in binario tramite divisione per~$2$, operazione 
ripetuta per ogni quoziente ottenuto. Il resto di ogni divisione, formato 
da $0$ o $1$, comporrà la stringa binaria mostrata nella tabella~\ref{tab:bin}.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

$\left.
\begin{array}{r | c}
        42280 & 0\\
        21140 & 0\\
        10570 & 0\\
        5285 & 1\\
        2642 & 0\\
        1321 & 1\\
        660 & 0\\
        330 & 0\\
        165 & 1\\
        82 & 0\\
        41 & 1\\
        20 & 0\\
        10 & 0\\
        5 & 1\\
        2 & 0\\
        1 & 1\\
        0 & /\\
\end{array}
\right\uparrow$

\caption{Codifica del resto in binario}\label{tab:bin} 
\end{table}

Il risultato derivante dalla codifica, letto dal basso verso l'alto come 
\mbox{indicato} dalla freccia della tabella~(\ref{tab:bin}), è il seguente:
\begin{quote}
$42280_{10}= \bm{1010010100101000_{2}}$
\end{quote}

\item Si avrà una Funzione Booleana a quattro variabili associata alla stringa 
binaria ``$1010010100101000$'' come nella tabella~\ref{tab:Fun}.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\iffalse % comment for the long table
$\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
    x & y & z & w & f(x, y, z, w) \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{array}$
\fi % comment for the long table

%\iffalse % uncomment for the long table
$\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
    x & y & z & w & f(x, y, z, w) \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}$\qquad\qquad
$\begin{array}{cccc|c} 
    x & y & z & w & f(x, y, z, w) \\
    \hline
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
\end{array}$
%\fi % uncomment for the long table


\caption{Funzione Booleana a quattro variabili associata alla stringa binaria}
\label{tab:Fun} 
\end{table}

bla bla vla

\end{document}
```

Don't worry about table placement until the document is finished.

[image]

Comment: U are the besttttt!!! It work!!! Grazie grazie grazieeeee!!!

Answer (score 0):

- Your document example is still not compilable,
- As I noted in my comment, list `enumerate` should use and start with `\item` . In MWE below I add them blindly.
- For captions of tables outside of `tables` float you should use `\captionof{table}{...}`.
- Why you use `\\`  for terminate text lines?. If there should start new paragraph, it is correct to insert empty text line.
- Changes in my MWE in comparison with yours are marked in code by `% <---`.

```
\documentclass[demo,
               a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

\usepackage{textpos}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,
              format=plain,
              position=bottom,
              font=small,
              labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\ }}
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} Luca \\ \textbf{Cognome:} blabla \\
\textbf{Matricola:} blabla}
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} 21-22}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{blabla} \\
    \Large\texttt{blabla}
\end{figure}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Introduzione}
blablabla
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduzione}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage

\section{blabla}

blablabla;

\hspace{12pt}\textbf{blabla}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   blablabla           % <----
\begin{textblock*}{180pt}(180pt, 5pt)
\begin{tabular}{r | c}
        42280 & 0\\
        21140 & 0\\
        10570 & 0\\
        5285  & 1\\
        2642  & 0\\
        1321  & 1\\
        660   & 0\\
        330   &  0\\
        165   & 1\\
        82    & 0\\
        41    & 1\\
        20    & 0\\
        10    & 0\\
        5     & 1\\
        2     & 0\\
        1     & 1\\
        0     & /\\
\end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Codifica del resto in binario}  % <---
    \label{tab: bin}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{150pt}(250pt, -5 pt)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0, -10) {};
    \node (B) at (0, 0) {};
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{textblock*}
\newpage
\item   blablabla:     

\hspace{4cm} blablabla 
\item   blablabla:
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc||c}
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x, y, z, w)$ \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\

\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Funzione Booleana a quattro variabili associata alla stringa binaria}
    \label{tab: Fun}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE (now) works as expected.

Comment: I deleted items by mistake.
I use \\ to space out one text from another.
I did as you said but it doesn't work.

Comment: I corrected the code, look above

Comment: @LucaLongo, I see, Now you are use my correction of your code in my answer (and not seeing worth to upvote it ...). So it works fine as my original code. Tell us, what is actually your problem! Your claims in question not hold!